# Sum of normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability

Let's say X~N(0,4) and Y~N(1,1). According to what law is this random variable distributed: Z=X+2Y. 
What confuses me is that I get different answers depending on the way I solve this (using characteristic functions). If I write Z=X+2Y=X+Y+Y I get that the answer is Z~N(2,6), but if I use this formula: if Y=b+aX then $\phi_Y(t)=e^{itb}\cdot\phi_X(at)$ my answer becomes Z~N(2,8), so what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you (automatically) assuming the two $Y$s to be independent random variables when you write $X + Y + Y$? That's not valid.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about this